# Delete video when it is playing on Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a web form, which uploads automatically a video though ashx(to a temporary folder) when it is selected. The thing is that once the video has been uploaded correctly, I display it on a div (using video.js) within the same page. The problem is that when the user finish filling all the fields on the form, and he/she clicks on submit(get postback), I try to move that file to another folder, but I get an error saying that the file is being used by another process. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Don't feel tempted to approve bad edit suggestions, there's nothing wrong with rejecting those. :) This one was so wrong I rolled it back.

Comment: Anyway, can you show how you're loading the file? You should be able to open it differently, but it's hard to tell how specifically in your case, without seeing what you're doing now.